# Getting exception "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client" only when using NServiceBus pub/sub method

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a console application project (will be moved to a windows service) that continuously generates some XML files based on data from an Oracle database and stores them in some folders. It works great.

**New Requirement**

Now we have received a request from the client that we have to send the XMLs or their parts to some web service as well.

**Solution 1**

Create another windows service which will keep watching the different folders and retrieve the newly created XML file and perform its operations on it.

Issues with this approach

- Another process/user could be reading the file at any time
- Cant track of which file has been read as I cannot move the file anywhere nor can I rename it to identify that its already been read
- User can move the file to some other unknown folder before my application read it  etc etc

**Solution 2**

Use `NServiceBus` in app1 to place the generated XML file's data in an MSMQ. The second application will retrieve it from there and do whatever it has to do. This seems a good idea as it automatically handles many situations itself.

I am using `StructureMap` for dependency injection in my application. I used the `PubSub` sample application to take help from. I configured my original XML generating application as `Publisher`.  It works for simple scenarios but I get an exception when I try to use it with my actual production code which accesses the remote Oracle db using a VPN. The exception occurs when `StructureMap` tries to create the objects I use as dependencies. The exception raises during this chain of objects creation, when the code tries to create an `OracleConnection` object. The inner most exception says

`The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client`.

This exception is totally misleading as I have successfully been using the same code till now. It even worked properly when I initially used `NServiceBus`' `Send` method with least configurations but begin to occur as soon as I moved to implementing a `Publisher` pattern.

Currently my settings in publisher application are as follows:

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="AuditConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AuditConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings />
  </UnicastBusConfig>  

  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />

  <AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
</configuration>
```

**EndpointConfig**

```
class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        ConfigureStructureMap();
        ConfigureNServiceBus();
    }

    private void ConfigureStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.Scan(
                scan =>
                {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.Assembly("Business");
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                }
                );

            config.For<ILogger>().Singleton().Use<LogManager>();
        });
    }

    private void ConfigureNServiceBus()
    {
        Configure.Serialization.Xml();

        //Disable transactions
        Configure.Transactions.Disable();

        Configure.With()
            .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
            .UseTransport<Msmq>();
    }
}
```

**ServerEndpoint**

```
public class ServerEndpoint : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    public void Start()
    {
        //this code throws the exception
        var wpaXmlManager = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITaskSchedular>();
        wpaXmlManager.StartImport();
    }

    public void Stop() { }
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's your Oracle client and server version?

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is escalation of transactions.

You see, the `Publish` method looks up the list of subscribers in the NServiceBus subscription storage (RavenDB by default). This is probably happening in the same unit of work as your Oracle code which then tries to enlist in the same transaction, potentially causing an escalation to a distributed transaction.

You may need a different version of the Oracle client library to get support for distributed transactions.

That being said, in this specific case, you would **probably** be safe turning off transactions with NServiceBus - seeing as you're doing work with the file system which isn't transactional in any case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. I just checked it by calling Configure.Transactions.Disable(); as well. Same problem.. :( I have updated my question to reflect what I did in ConfigureNServiceBus() method.

Comment: can you please help? I am stuck.

Comment: What are you using Oracle for?

Comment: Our client organization uses Oracle databases for their data. I have to generate XML documents based on some table's data in that Oracle DB.

Comment: Could you cache the data from the Oracle DB at startup and then use that cache as a part of your message processing?

Comment: I dont think this is possible as this is not a one time DB access methodology. My service continuously checks the DB after specific intervals for any new records, and then creates XML file(s) based on that data. I dont know in advance if there is any data present in the beginning. I have to poll the DB for any new records.

Comment: So if you're doing a simple query against Oracle, then I'd suggest suppressing the transactions for that call.